# Error while converting s3 bucket image url to base64

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Can somebody help me to get the base64 of image URL uploaded on the AWS s3 bucket.
I am getting CORS error everytime even after setting multiple setting on S3 CORS configuration.
Below is my code and CORS setting.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    callback(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
};

xhr.onerror = function() {

}
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: I've had this issue in the past, and it just took some time for the CORS settings to be effective on previously existing assets. Do you reproduce the issue if you upload a brand new image now, and try to access it with your script? Your script works for me on a public S3 bucket with CORS set up like you did ([this image](https://shrt-statics.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/160x200.jpg))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes I am able to reproduce this issue for new asset also. And also tried to test on old assets after 1-2 Hours of setting CORS config.

Comment: Ok, that's weird. Do you have the problem too, if you use the image URL I provided above, which seems to work for me? _(to check if the problem comes from the code, or from the bucket settings)_

Comment: My code is working with the image mentioned by you.

Comment: My problem working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.